# How mitigate the lack of Switch/Case statements in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the good way to handle cases like below in Python? I would use Switch/Case break pattern in Java, but not sure what is the best way in Python.

The code below simply simulates 6 sided die rolls and prints their occurrences in 10000 rolls. My `if else` solution does work, but simply looks awful, so advice for a better solution would be much appreciated.

```
from random import randint

i = 0
ii = 0
iii = 0
iv = 0
v = 0
vi = 0

for trial in range(0, 10000):
    die = randint(1, 6)
    if die == 1:
        i += 1
    elif die == 2:
        ii += 1
    elif die == 3:
        iii += 1
    elif die == 4:
        iv += 1
    elif die == 5:
        v += 1
    else:
        vi += 1

print("i = {}, ii = {}, iii = {}, iv = {}, v = {}, vi = {}"
      .format(i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi))
```

Comment: I'm curious how a switch/case statement looks much better in this context ... :-)

Comment: I suggest you look into dictionaries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just don't define 6 variables but a `list`:

```
from random import randint

rolls = [0]*6

for trial in range(0, 10000):
    die = randint(1, 6)
    rolls[die-1] += 1

print("i = {}, ii = {}, iii = {}, iv = {}, v = {}, vi = {}"
      .format(*rolls))
```

note the nice argument passing to `format` using `*`.

Comment: Yep, this is what I was about to propose :-)

Comment: a **list**! a **list**

Comment: I see that Rob has exactly the same solution too.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, been answering too much C questions lately :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Honestly, I'm being pedantic. Indeed, the CPython implementation *is* a resizable array list, but still... that's an implementation detail!

Comment: Ok, yes that is much better

Answer (score 2):

There are a lots of questions like this

> You can do this easily enough with a sequence of if... elif... elif...
> else. There have been some proposals for switch statement syntax, but
> there is no consensus (yet) on whether and how to do range tests. See
> [PEP 275](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0275/) for complete details and the current status.
>
> For cases where you need to choose from a very large number of
> possibilities, you can create a dictionary mapping case values to
> functions to call. For example:
>
> ```
> def function_1(...):
>     ...
>
>
> functions = {'a': function_1,
>              'b': function_2,
>              'c': self.method_1, ...}
>
> func = functions[value] 
> func()
> ```

from [Why isn’t there a switch or case statement in Python?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

For a more generalized case, you could use a dictionary. How is this useful at all? Well, lets say you want random numbers between 1001 and 1006, instead of 1 and 6. Using a list, you would have to add 1000 placeholders. This is not necessary when using a dictionary.

```
from random import randint

rolls = {
    1001: 0,
    1002: 0,
    1003: 0,
    1004: 0,
    1005: 0,
    1006: 0
}

for trial in range(0, 10000):
    die = randint(1001, 1006)
    rolls[die] += 1

print("1001 = {}, 1002 = {}, 1003 = {}, 1004 = {}, 1005 = {}, 1006 = {}"
      .format(rolls[1001], rolls[1002], rolls[1003], rolls[1004], rolls[1005], rolls[1006]))
```